# Python: Looping through directory and saving each file using filename as data frame name

Tags: python, pandas, loops, assign

In `R` there is a function called `assign` which assigns a value to a name in the environment.

EG:

```
assign("Hello", 2)
> Hello
[1] 2
```

In python I can't seem to do the same. I initially tried:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os

for file in os.listdir('C:\\Users\\Olivia\\Documents'):
    if file.endswith(".csv"):
        os.path.splitext(file)[0] = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\Olivia\\Documents\\' + file)
```

But I can see this is trying to make a string equal to a file which doesn't work.

I managed to get all the files in a list by doing:

```
import glob

dl = glob.glob(r'C:\Users\Olivia\Documents\*.csv')
nl = []
for i in dl:
    pl = i.split(os.sep)
    name = pl[5][:-4]
    nl.append(name)

ddict = {}

 for k, v in zip(nl,dl):
    ddict[k] = ddict.get(k,"") + v

 dfl = []

 for k, v in ddict.items():
    dfl.append(read_csv(v))
```

But now how do I get each data frame out of the list and named as the file without the extension. There must be a way to assign each data frame in the list as a name from the file list

Comment: I got the list from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30246620/how-to-create-separate-pandas-dataframes-for-each-csv-file-and-give-them-meaning

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Honestly, you were on the right track with your first method. Unfortunately, python doesn't give you the option to create a "variable number of variables" dynamically, as you have tried and realised already. *However*! You *can* create a dictionary and assign dataframes to string keys as you like. Here's how.

```
root = 'C:\\Users\\Olivia\\Documents'

ddict = {}
for file in os.listdir(root):
    if file.endswith(".csv"):
        name = os.path.splitext(file)[0]
        ddict[name] = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(root, file))
```

Another way of building this dictionary is using a *dict comprehension*:

```
ddict = {os.path.splitext(file)[0] : pd.read_csv(os.path.join(root, file)) 
                for file in os.listdir(root) if file.endswith('csv')
}
```

Now, referring to a single dataframe is as easy as

```
ddict['your_file_name']
```

Another thing to note, the *safest* way to join files is using `os.path.join`. It's just safer than a plain `+`.

---

**References**

- [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)
- [why use os.path.join over string concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944387/why-use-os-path-join-over-string-concatenation)

Comment: Brilliant, and then with the final dictionary is there a way to take everything out as individual objects? I know this would be less efficient and unnecessary, but im curious if its easy to do.

Comment: @Olivia Really it's not recommended, but it is possible. You use: `globals().update(ddict)` but this leads to code smell, it's better to just leave it inside a dictionary.

Comment: @Olivia `os.path.join` will automatically take care of adding the separator if it does not exist. If you really want to concat to strings (as opposed to joining file sub paths), then use `+`. Otherwise, to join subpaths, it's considered good practice to use `os.path.join`, and it is portable too.